# Проверить, пустое ли свойство PHP

Tags: php, битрикс

Всем привет! Вывожу свойство в Битрикс вот так:

```
Небольшой текст — <? echo $arResult['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['SVOISTVO']['DISPLAY_VALUE'];?>
```

Если свойство пустое, то результат выглядит так:

```
Небольшой текст —
```

Как сделать так, чтобы если свойство пустое, ничего не выводилось (имею ввиду небольшой текст)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать краткую запись оператора `if ... else`:

```php
<?php echo ( empty($arResult['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['SVOISTVO']['DISPLAY_VALUE']) )? '' : 'Небольшой текст — ' . $arResult['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['SVOISTVO']['DISPLAY_VALUE']; ?>
```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо!

Comment: В таком случае не будут выводиться нули, если они есть. Иногда бывает такое, что в свойствах есть такие, у которых значения - нули, и их нужно выводить. Для таких случаев этот вариант не подойдет - там нужно делать дополнительные проверки.